# ngrok returns 419 in laravel 6 with disable CSRF Token

Tags: php, laravel

I am using ngrok and laravel 6 to be able to do a project with Transbank, everything is fine at the time of making the POST request, my code
Web Routes

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('webpayplus/welcomeWebPay');
});

Route::post('/started', 'WebPayPlussController@initPayWeb')->name('start');

Route::post('/confirm_pay', 'WebPayPlussController@confirmPay')->name('front');
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Transbank\Webpay\WebpayPlus;
use Transbank\Webpay\WebpayPlus\Transaction;


class WebPayPlussController extends Controller
{

   public function __construct(){
       
       WebpayPlus::configureForIntegration('597055555532', '579B532A7440BB0C9079DED94D31EA1615BACEB56610332264630D42D0A36B1C');
   }

   public function initPayWeb(Request $request){

       
           $buy_order ='abc456';
           $session_id='4784568';
           $amount=10000;
           $response = (new Transaction)->create(
               $buy_order, 
               $session_id, 
               $amount,
           Route('front'));

       $url =$response->getUrl().'?token_ws='.$response->getToken();
       return redirect()->away($url);
       
       
   }

   public function confirmPay(Request $request){
      
       
           $confirm=  (new Transaction)->commit($request->get('token_ws'));

       if($confirmacion->isApproved()){
           return 'is Approved';
       }else{
           return 'is not Approved';
       }
       
      
      
     
   }

   
}
```

view blade php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Transbank</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            
            
                <div class="card mb-4">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    
                        <h5 class="card-title" >Web Pay Plus</h5>
                        <p class="card-text"> Pagos con WebPayPlus</p>
                        
                        <form method="POST" action="{{route('start')}}" >
                                @csrf
                             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Enviar">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
         


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I do is start the `php artisan server --host = my-ip-address --port = 8000` then i run for ngrok `ngrok http my-ip-address: 8000` getting the url from ngrok, but when starting the "started" route directs Transbank, the problem is when returning the URL to the "confirm_pay" route it shows a 419 error, the page expired.

I have tried disabling CSRF checking in VerifyCsrfToken as follows

```
class VerifyCsrfToken 
{
   use InteractsWithTime;

   protected $except = [
       'confirm_pay/confirmPay',
       'started/initPayWeb'
     ];
}
```

but i keep getting this problem
[image: Error in route]

Comment: If it's a callback url then exclude it from CSRF checks (in out `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware) since you are at that point expecting a cross-site request to happen rather than trying to prevent one.

Comment: it does not work

Comment: I get this sometimes when not using https:// How difficult would it be to setup ssl ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the code below in app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```php
public function boot()
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
```