Accessing API server through ngrok causing 419
(I have been digging this for over 24 hours now and have tried everything that I could find online), so there is a lot of detail, but I'll try to keep it as objective as I can).
I'm trying to access my locally running servers through ngrok. There are two servers involved:

Laravel server running on https (port 443) that hosts the backend API. Using Sanctum for authentication and session cookie/token. Lives inside a docker container. Port 443 is mapped to host machine's 15443.
Vite server running on the host machine on port 3000. This is a Vue SPA Connects to Laravel API using axios.

Both servers work fine and can talk to each other locally, i.e. I can open https://localhost:3000 in my browser, successfully login. Laravel sets session cookie and subsequent API calls (e.g. /login, /home) authenticate and return data successfully.
Now I'm trying to make my SPA available to outside world through ngrok. Successfully completed all ngrok configuration. Two tunnels created on the host machine; one for the Laravel server's mapped port (15443) and other for the locally running Vite SPA (3000). I can now type ngrok-provided proxy URL for the Vite server in my browser and it successfully tunnels into my locally running Vite server and shows the website. When the SPA calls login API endpoint, even though the sanctum/csrf-cookie call succeeds (status 204), the subsequent call to /login endpoint returns the infamous status 419.
After pulling my hair for hours, I have discovered that unlike local use, the ngrok way of accessing Laravel server through the SPA does not set XSRF-TOKEN cookie in response to sanctum/csrf-cookie endpoint, which causes 419. To resolve this issue I have tried the following:

Setting SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS to include ngrok-provided URL of the SPA
Setting SESSION_DOMAIN to ngrok-free.app
Setting SESSION_SAME_SITE to lax and even none
Setting Referer header in axios
Setting withCredentials and withXSRFToken prop in axios
Adding both ngrok-provided URL as well as local Vite URL in SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS

None of these has fixed the problem. I really don't understand if this is ngrok's problem of not passing server cookies to the tunneled SPA, or if my Laravel server is not recognizing my SPA through the tunneled request.
I'm using Laravel 11, Apache, PHP 8.3 and current version of docker on the server-side. On the client-side, it is latest Vue + Axios (but that shouldn't matter AFAICS).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69169591/ngrok-returns-419-in-laravel-6-with-disable-csrf-token  or changing SESSION_DRIVER

@Mate: That didn't work.  SESSION_DRIVER is also set to cookie. Thanks for the input though.
